# How can i use onTap in Grid View in flutter to navigate to specific pages?

Tags: android, flutter

Here's my code

*This is the code of my homepage where I used the Grid View widget. I declared a list where I specified a name, icon path, and a boolean. Item builder is connected to the code of a different page and it's given below this code*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../util/service_box.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final double horizontalPadding = 25;
  final double verticalPadding = 25;

  // list of services
  List services = [
    ["Background\nRemover", "assets/background_remove.png", true],
    ["QR\nGenerator", "assets/qr.png", false],
    ["Scanner", "assets/scanner.png", false],
    ["Calculator", "assets/calculator.png", true],
    ["Text to\nSpeech", "assets/tts.png", false],
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: horizontalPadding, vertical: verticalPadding),
              child: IconButton(
                iconSize: 50,
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.tips_and_updates,
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: horizontalPadding),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text("Welcome to",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.grey[700]),
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    "APPY TOOLBOX",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 37,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 25),

            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: horizontalPadding),
              child: Divider(
                color: Colors.grey[500],
                thickness: 1,
              ),
            ),

            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: horizontalPadding),
              child: const Text('Services'),
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: GridView.builder(
                  itemCount: services.length,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      childAspectRatio: 1/1.3,
                    ),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ServiceBox(
                        serviceName: services[index][0],
                        iconPath: services[index][1],
                        color: services[index][2],
                      );
                    },
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*Now, here's the page containing the item builder. Here i have used the list i created to create a new UI for the containers...*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ServiceBox extends StatelessWidget {
  final String serviceName;
  final String iconPath;
  final bool color;

  ServiceBox(
      {Key? key,
      required this.serviceName,
      required this.iconPath,
      required this.color})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: color ? Colors.grey[900] : Colors.grey[200],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Image.asset(iconPath, height: 50, color: color ? Colors.white : Colors.black,),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                      child: Text(
                        serviceName,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 17,
                          color: color ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**What I want is:** ***To add onTap functionality to these containers, so that each of them navigates to a different page when clicked.***

Comment: you can pass another param servicePath and use it to navigate to another page.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your builder section with Inkwell or GestureDetector like so:

```
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                  ServiceBox(
                    serviceName: services[index][0],
                    iconPath: services[index][1],
                    color: services[index][2],
                    onTap:(){
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                         MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context)=> YourScreenName(),
                       ),
                      );
                    }
                  ),
                 );
                },
```

Comment: no but there are multiple services and different pages are assigned. how can i open different page on clicking different services

Comment: this is the logic that you need to implement from your data index, you have to make a switch case or if statement or you make static names based on your index, for example


 Navigator.of(context).push(
                         MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context)=> services[index][index_of_screens],
                       ),

while your index_of_screens should return the route name